# Android Build Error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ResolveInfo

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and am attempting to append a menu item to the Cut/Copy/Paste context menu globally based on https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/in-app-translations-in-android.html. I understand that `getSupportedActivities()` is returning an object that cannot be made compatible with ResolveInfo but am not sure what action to take to correct this.

I have the following within my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
    android:label="@string/process_text">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this within `ProcessTextActivity.java`

```
package com.my-app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ProcessTextActivity extends Activity {
    TextView mTextView;

    private Intent createProcessTextIntent() {
        return new Intent()
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT)
                .setType("text/plain");
    }

    private List getSupportedActivities() {
        PackageManager packageManager =
                mTextView.getContext().getPackageManager();
        return packageManager.queryIntentActivities(createProcessTextIntent(), 0);
    }

    public void onInitializeMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Start with a menu Item order value that is high enough
        // so that your "PROCESS_TEXT" menu items appear after the
        // standard selection menu items like Cut, Copy, Paste.
        int menuItemOrder = 100;
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : getSupportedActivities()) {
            menu.add(
                    Menu.NONE,
                    Menu.NONE,
                    menuItemOrder++,
                    getLabel(resolveInfo))
                    .setIntent(createProcessTextIntentForResolveInfo(resolveInfo))
                    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        }
    }

    private Intent createProcessTextIntentForResolveInfo(ResolveInfo info) {
        return createProcessTextIntent()
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, !
                        mTextView.onCheckIsTextEditor())
                .setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName,
                        info.activityInfo.name);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to build I get the following error:

```
ProcessTextActivity.java:33: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ResolveInfo
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : getSupportedActivities()) {
                                                         ^
ProcessTextActivity.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
                getLabel(resolveInfo))
                ^

  symbol:   method getLabel(ResolveInfo)
  location: class ProcessTextActivity
  2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `packageManager.queryIntentActivities(createProcessTextIntent(), 0)` returns `List<ResolveInfo>` ( i checked on the decompiled class `PackageManager` class from android studio), this means you are allowed to use :

```
 private List<ResolveInfo> getSupportedActivities() {
        PackageManager packageManager =
                mTextView.getContext().getPackageManager();
        return packageManager.queryIntentActivities(createProcessTextIntent(), 0);
    }
```

By using the code above you won't get the error anymore, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. this did the trick. I'm still seeing the `getLabel` error. It seems to me that it expects `getLabel` to be defined within the class and expects it to return `MenuItem` (given that `.setIntent` is called on `getLabel()`. However, I'm not sure how to pull a `MenuItem` from `ResolveInfo`

Comment: @TylersSN In the link you provided they say :The label for each item can be retrieved with:
`resolveInfo.loadLabel(mPackageManager);` so maybe this is the `getLabel()` function

Comment: Thanks, was just about to circle back with an answer as I was notified of your response. This did the trick: `public CharSequence getLabel(ResolveInfo resolveInfo) { return ResolveInfo.loadLabel(mTextView.getContext().getPackageManager()); }`

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)